# Ignite and CAP theoram

Tags: ignite

1.Which category of CAP theoram does ignite fall under ?

2.While doing a loadCache using a client on multiple Servers , after the loadCache being called if the client goes down, will the operation complete on the Servers ?(Unable to try it due to some permission restriction)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ignite guarantees data consistency. In case of cluster is segmented into two parts, they can't be merged back. One of the parts has to be considered invalid and restarted.
2. Most likely data will not be fully loaded in this case. The loading process should be restarted.

Comment: Does nt the loadCache call localloadCache on all the servers ?

Comment: It does, but you don't have guarantee that all data is loaded until the client receives all responses and returns from loadCache method.

Comment: What if loadCache is an async call ? the servers must continue loading the cache irrespective of the clients presence .

Comment: Async call only changes behavior on the client. If you need to have guarantee that the data is loaded, you have to do this synchronously and wait for the process to finish. If something goes wrong, you can retry.

Answer (score 0):

For the first question: the enum of CacheAtomicityMode has two values

1. TRANSACTIONAL: if you configure this in you CacheConfigure, then your application is CP
2. ATOMIC: if you configure this in you CacheConfigure, then your application is AP, and ATOMIC is the default value.

For the second question: if your client is embeddedwith your application，locaCache failed for some reason, then CacheLoaderException will be throw. If you want to custome CacheStore，you can extend CacheStoreAdapter and override method.